# Individual emails triggering a warning: HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag Your message should contain an <html> tag

Tags: civimail

When sending individual emails in Civi, we're getting warning about their not being HTML tags in our HTML-only emails.

Is there a way to change this?

Should we just use plain-text emails when mailing individuals?

Comment: Is that the _exact_ text of the warning? `HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag` ? What CMS and are there any plugins that might be outputting that?

Comment: we're using WordPress, I don't think its a plugin or extension... this comes up specifically when sending a non-newsletter using the "Send an email" feature where we don't have a plain-text version of the email.  This is the warning we get from mail-tester.com: https://snipboard.io/kFYvB9.jpg

Comment: Oh it's from mail-tester. I guess civi could add an `<html>` tag before sending if the html section doesn't contain any.

Comment: Is there a way for me to add this myself?

Comment: I think so with a little custom extension using https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMailParams/